# fgetc,getc causes the program to crash when reading from text file

Tags: c, file, input, fgetc, getc

Whats wrong? I'm pretty sure my syntax is correct since it has no warnings. Plus it won't go past `getc(document);` I tried `fgetc(document);` same result. What am I not getting here? (I used `printf("$");` to see where it crashes)

```
char temp[51];
int cntr = 0,listcntr = 0,buffer;
FILE *document;
contact list[MAXCONTACTS];
document = fopen("addressbook.txt","r");
do
{
    for(cntr = 0;cntr < 51; cntr++)
        temp[cntr] = '\0';
    cntr = 0;
    do
    {

        buffer = getc(document);
         printf("$");
        if(buffer != '\t')
            temp[cntr] = buffer;
        ++cntr; 
    }while(buffer != '\t'&& buffer != EOF);
list[listcntr].name = temp;
```

Comment: What language are you using? The way you declare document seems really strange to me

Comment: Is this: `document = ("addressbook.txt","r");` valid? Seems like you are missing `fopen`

Comment: oh sorry must have been during copy paste. will fix that

Comment: I would suggest you debug and watch cntr to check if it does not exceed 51 by chance. If that is not possible add debug printing statement for its value.

Comment: Also, use `feof()` to check for EOF.

Comment: Do you check what fopen() returns?

Comment: yeah, I'm pretty sure its there. Cause in the main fuction I made it check if fopen("addressbook.txt","r") == NULL

Comment: Could you post full snippet what you have here is not syntactically correct. For example there is an extra `do{`

Comment: if (fopen() == NULL) { error!!!! } lese { go ahead; }

Comment: @Ivan: exactly. It doesn't even compile so it can never crash.

Comment: @wildplasser its just a snippet. Didn't include header files and the other functions, I thought people here hated walls of code

Comment: people here dislike walls of code, just as they dislike code that doesn't compile. Just remove everything that is not required to reproduce the error. Leave the rest of the code in a condition it compiles. Also add information about the kind of crash, and potentially a stacktrace.

Comment: It is not a snippet, it is incomplete code. The first `do {` *could* end in a `} while (c=fgetc(stdin);` or whatever. The missing part of the block could do *anything*, including `memset(temp, 42, 1333);`.

Comment: have you made sure the output is flushed as you expect it to be flushed? change to `printf("this never happens\n");` (mind the newline character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I modified your code a little and added a couple of checks, maybe it will be enough.

```
char temp[51];
int listcntr = 0,buffer;
contact list[MAXCONTACTS];
FILE *document = fopen("addressbook.txt","r");

if (NULL == document){
    //exit here
}

for(int i = 0;i < 51; i++){
    temp[i] = '\0';
}

int cntr = 0;
for (int cntr=0; cntr < 51 && !feof(document); cntr++){
    buffer = getc(document);
    if (buffer == '\t'){
        break;
    }
    temp[cntr] = buffer;
}

if(listcntr < MAXCONTACTS){
    // you should probably copy temp here
    list[listcntr].name = temp;
}
```